# Yii3 and Docker: how to install and run a project

Tags: php, docker, yii, yii2

i know that Yii3 is in developing, but i want to try and explore it.
I want to install it and run with Docker but i've never used Docker so i'm in difficult:
How can i install Yii3 and run it using Docker in **Windows 10**?

At the moment i had only execute:
*composer create-project yiisoft/app --prefer-dist --stability=dev your_project*

Thanks in advance
ps: please write all steps from start to end

Comment: There is repository with docker https://github.com/yiisoft/yii-docker

Comment: ok but i'm new in docker, what should i do with this repo?
i have to download this repo in my pc?
download image with docker?
download image and framework?
PLEASE WRITE ALL STEPS